# Can I Create a Web API project with Single Page or Multi Page View(UI) without using MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I Would like to create a project (basically Restful API Project) using Web API to target  multiple customers from different platforms.

here I have a few requirements:

1. I should be able to Expose the API.
2. I would like to have the View(UI) also either single/multi page, (without using the MVC).

Right now I'm using one controller to refer to my View(index.cshtml), but I would like to remove that controller.so is there any other alternative to refer/use my UI Page without using MVC or should I use MVC along with Web API.

Comment: yes it is possible to consume data from webapi and fill any html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Laks, with the help of your response:

1. I have created index.html page at root level and made it as the startup page.
2. when I run the project it has opened the index.html page.
3. as I wanted to open Index.cshtml file as startup page, I have moved my Index.cshtml page from Views/Home folder to root level and made it as startup page(removed previously created index.html) but it didn't work.

after searching few links in stack overflow, I got to know that directly accessing Razor Design(cshtml) files is disabled by default, and to enable this I have to change the following parameter in the web.config file:

Default:

```
add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"
```

Change to:

```
add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"
```

Now I'm able to access the Razor Design directly without any problems.
Please let me know if it is a bad practice to access Razor design(cshtml) files directly.
Thanks to Laks,

Comment: How did you make index.html file startup? It shows me 403.14

Answer (score 1):

You can make a normal HTML file, or you can use Razor directly (via ASP.Net WebPages) without MVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot Laks. I Would like to use Razor Design view(.cshtml). Could you please give me any links on how to use Razor with WebAPI?

Comment: @Sudhakar: Razor has nothing to do with web API.  Just make a normal Razor view, then use Javascript to make AJAX requests.

Comment: i have removed the controller which refers my view but now i'm getting error as: "Server Error in '/' Application,The Resource can not be found" but if i use the controller it is working fine. could you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: What URL? Do you have a `.cshtml` file there?

Comment: url : http://localhost:60961/ ,yes .cshtml file is there inside Views\Home folder.

Comment: @Sudhakar: Views are an MVC concept.  If you aren't using MVC, you need to create a file matching the URL you want.  For `/`, you need `~/index.cshtml`.